# Meteor.js programmatic redirecting to different website

Tags: meteor

How do I programmatic redirect to different URL using Meteor.js.

I tried following but didn't work.

```
Template.someTemplate.events({
    "click #process": function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Do some important stuff
        window.location = "https://example.com";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work. Maybe if you add the href in:

```
Template.someTemplate.events({
    "click #process": function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Do some important stuff
        window.location.href = "https://example.com";
    }
});
```